# File History Catalog and Restoring Backup Image ... What Will Happen?

Tags: windows, backup, backup-restoration

The Windows 10 File History feature stores the configuration files and catalog files both on the local C: and the File History target drive (correct me if I'm wrong please) and keeps them in sync.  Is there any documentation or accounts of what happens when someone restores a backup image of their C:?  The backup image would contain a different catalog (and possibly configuration) file for File History than what is stored on the File History target.  Is Windows smart enough to check which catalog is newer and use that one?  Or will it overwrite the catalog on the target drive (which would result in some lost history).  Or does it throw an error?